# assigning different number into the same variable for differnt csv files

Tags: python, variables, graph, assign

```
for item in T:
    if ["twang10_1.csv","twang10_2.csv","twang10_3.csv"]:
        l=0.10
    elif ["twang12_1.csv","twang12_2.csv","twang12_3.csv"]:
        l=0.12
    elif ["twang14_1.csv","twang14_2.csv","twang14_3.csv"]:
        l=0.14
```

i have assigned these 3 different values for l which is length. and on 1 click run for 9 files they caluculate youngs modulus using different values of l which i tried to assign there. but the code only says 0.1 9 times when i check for print(l).

im expecting it goes through 9 times changing the value of l every 3 files as it runs

Comment: Your `if` statements don't make much sense. They're not testing anything. Did you mean `if item == [...]`?

Comment: Or maybe `if item in [...]`?

Comment: The way you've written it, the first `if` condition will always succeed, because a non-empty list is truthy.

Comment: If the filenames always follow that pattern, you could use `if item.startswith("twang10_"):`

Comment: And if the value of `l` is always arithmetically related to the number after `twang`, you could use a regular expression to extract the number, then divide it by 100. So `twang10 => 10 => 10/100 == 0.10`